# Link Django models together

Tags: python, django

Hi I have two background functions that fetch data from an api and update models every few seconds calling `.save()`

The models updated like that are `MBEvent` and `MBOrders`

I would like to map the data between the models using foreign key.
`event_id`
`temp_id`
`runner_id` are the primary key for the three models.

I would like to map 
`runner_1_back_odds` `runner_2_back_odds` `runner_1_lay_odds` `runner_2_lay_odds`  from `MBEvent` as `current_back_odds` and `current_lay_odds` to `MBBet`

I haven't been able to get foreign keys to work in django. Is it possible what I'm requesting with foreign keys?
What I really want is that when MBEvent is updated the data is also updated in MBBet. Do foreign keys work to map the models together and ensure integrity with the data?

```
class MBEvent(models.Model):
     event_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
     event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
     start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
     is_ip = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
     runner_1_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
     runner_2_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
     runner_1_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
     runner_2_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
     runner_1_back_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
     runner_2_back_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
     runner_1_lay_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
     runner_2_lay_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)

class MBOrders(models.Model):
    temp_id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=300)
    runner_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    runner_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pot_pro = models.IntegerField(null= True)
    rem_pot_pro = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pot_lib = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    side = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=8)
    stake = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


class MBBet(models.Model):
    runner_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    runner_name = models.ForigenKey(MBEvent,on_delete=MODELS.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=300)
    current_back_odds = models.ForigenKey(MBEvent,on_delete=MODELS.CASCADE)
    current_lay_odds =  models.ForigenKey(MBEvent,on_delete=MODELS.CASCADE)
    bet_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    side = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=8)
    stake = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Comment: What did you try to make `ForeignKey`s work? I can't see you even used it anywhere.

Comment: @trixn I've just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set up the ForeignKey fields in your model, you can use them like so :

```
mb_event_one = MBEvent()
mb_event_two = MBEvent()

mb_bet = MBBet()
mb_bet.current_back_odds = mb_event_one
mb_bet.current_lay_odds = mb_event_two

mb_bet.save()
```

That way you can access the child properties directly from the parent :

```
mb_bet.current_back_odds.event_id  # == mb_event_one.event_id
mb_bet.current_lay_odds.event_name  # == mb_event_two.event_name
```

I would advise you to use clear and accurate names for your ForeignKey fields. If you link an event, it may be wiser to call your field `hosting_event` or something like that.

---

**EDIT :** Alright I see what you're trying to do.

ForeignKey fields are used to link **models** together, not fields.
You should use them like that :

```
class MBRunner(models.Model):
    # ...

class MBEvent(models.Model):
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    runner = models.ForeignKey(MBRunner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

my_runner = MBRunner()
my_event = MBEvent(runner=my_runner)
```

That way you can access all the runner's properties from the event.

```
my_event.runner.runner_name  # == my_runner.runner_name
```

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) again.